# Failover Cluster Problem

Tags: hyper-v, failovercluster

We have a problem with our Hyper-v Failover Cluster.Failover Cluster gives me MSDTC error.

I am receiving the following these errors.

> Cluster resource 'DTC' in clustered service or application 'Cluster Group' failed.
>
> The Cluster service failed to bring clustered service or application 'Cluster Group' completely > online or offline. One or more resources may be in a failed state. This may impact the 
>   availability of the clustered service or application.

After Validation test;

> Validate Resource Status
>
> ---
>
> This resource has a dependency configuration that does not include a Network Name and Physical Disk resource. This resource type is usually dependent on at least one Network Name and at least one Physical Disk resource. This setting may be acceptable if this cluster has a specific configuration requirement. An example may be a cluster using a storage resource type other than 'Physical Disk'. The dependencies for this resource can be changed through Failover Cluster Manager by clicking on the resource and selecting 'Properties', then choosing the 'Dependencies' tab.
>
> This resource is marked with a state of 'Failed' instead of 'Online'. This failed state indicates that the resource had a problem either coming online or had a failure while it was online. The event logs and cluster logs may have information that is helpful in identifying the cause of the failure.
>
> Validate Cluster Service And Driver Settings
>
> ---
>
> The "Cluster Group" contains one or more resources that are not recommended to be in the group. This group is used for management of the cluster and it is not recommended to add any other resources to this group. The following is a list of resources that are not required for failover cluster manager and therefore not recommended to be in this group: DTC.

What should I do?

Comment: You're going to have to give us a lot more than that sorry - let us know as much as possible about your configuration, what you've checked already etc. There's literally no way we can help you with this question as it stands and I'll have to close it if you don't give us a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a clustered hyper-v system does not need a msdtc resource to work!